# Only keep som groups when facetting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example. How can I limit the number of facets, e.g. only keep audi and dodge?

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_histogram(aes(displ)) +
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast workaround would be subsetting your data inside the `ggplot` call (check the accepted answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608133/plot-only-a-select-few-facets-in-facet-grid)).

In your case I believe that you should add a `subset(mpg,manufacturer %in% c("audi","dodge"))` call inside the first ggplot argument.

**Code**:

```
> ggplot(subset(mpg,manufacturer %in% c("audi","dodge"))) +
+     geom_histogram(aes(displ)) +
+     facet_wrap(~ manufacturer)
```

This produces the desired output:

[image: Audi and Dodge appear only]

**Edit:** Both answers appeared at the same time with the same solution

Answer (score 2):

What about this, working on the dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
# select only desired manifacturers
filter(manufacturer %in% c('audi','dodge')) %>%  
 ggplot() +
 geom_histogram(aes(displ)) +
 facet_wrap(~ manufacturer)
```

[image]

Comment: I  added a very similar answer below, very similar timing though (not intended)

Comment: @ s_t: I accepted the other ansewer to help his "reputation".

Comment: Not a problem, it's to you to choose the correct answer. @JustBurfi, I think you did not something wrong, when you know the answer, post it (it's to you decide if it's necessary or not).